# PHP MySqli GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database where I house my clients, I need to display them on a page grouped and ordered by State and City.

If I use the code below I get the result I want but the State duplicates for each city.
If I change the ORDER BY to GROUP BY then it only displays 1 result, there are several cities in the State and I obviously want them all listed under the relevant State.

Any help is welcome.

```
"SELECT state, city, company_name  FROM mytable WHERE status='T' AND city <>'Head Office' AND company_name <>'my company' ORDER BY state ASC"
```

Further code as requested below:

```
$coverage="";
$sql = "SELECT state, city, company_name  FROM mutable WHERE status='T' AND city <>'Head Office' AND company_name <>'my company' GROUP BY state, city ORDER BY state ASC, city ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$currentCity = NULL;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $state =$row["state"];
    $office = $row["city"]; 
    $agent = $row["company_name"]; 
    if($row["city"] !== $currentCity) {
        $currentCity = $row["city"];
        $coverage .= '
        <div id="stateCoverage" class="fluid ">
        <p><strong class="white">' . $state . '</strong></p>
        </div>
            <div id="officeCoverage" class="fluid ">
                <h3>' . $office . '</h3>
            </div> 
        ';
    }
    $coverage .= '
        <div id="imageCoverage" class="fluid ">
                <img src="http://foo/bar/logos/' . $agent . '.jpg" alt="' . $agent . '">
            </div>
    ';

}
}else{
$coverage="<p>There seems to have been a problem locating your content, please try again, if the problem persists we would be grateful if you reported it to us, Thank you.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Your query is fine. What you're trying to achieve is a task for the presentation layer, not for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are probably looking for it's something of this sorts:

```
SELECT 
    state, city, company_name
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    status = 'T' AND city <> 'Head Office'
    AND company_name <> 'my company'
group by state, city, company_name
ORDER BY state ASC, city ASC, company_name ASC
```

The **GROUP BY** operator collapses all the rows into a single row, as they match the parameters. To avoid collapsing all the records into a single row you just have to add more fields into that operator as you need.

Comment: But he still will have one row per city, i.e. duplicate state values.

Comment: Thanks @jimmy yes I tried all of parameters and I still get duplicates, it's like I need to split the query up, there will be no duplicates in the State but there could be in the Cities so I can't achieve anything with DISTINCT even though thats essentially what I want DISTINCT(State) only

Comment: @IanPither As said earlier, this is not something that can (or should) be done in SQL.

Comment: as @X.L.Ant says I think you are trying to solve the problem on the wrong side of it. You should elaborate your question adding the PHP code you are using and what's your expected result in order for us to help you better.

Comment: @jimmy, appreciated, maybe you could look at the live page and you'll see straight away what I'm expecting, http://arpad.property/coverage.php you'll that there are 2 lines for South Central one of which should have 2 logos within, all I need is the 'State' to be a heading as is the City