# Display a table with multiple columns that differ in condition for each column PHP MySQL

Tags: php, database, mysqli, html-table

I have this data in student table:

```
stu_id  stu_name   stu_exam   stu_exam_year  stu_mark  stu_grade  stu_est_mark  stu_est_grade
111     Alice      First      2015           80        A          
111     Alice      Mid        2015           75        B
111     Alice      Final      2015           65        B

222     Frankline  First      2015           75        B
222     Frankline  Mid        2015           60        B
222     Frankline  Final      2015           50        C
```

i want to output the data in a table form as below where estimate grade = total marks from each exam / total marks of full mark * 100

```
No    ID    Name       First-term Exam     Mid-term Exam       Final Exam         Estimated
                       Mark   |  Grade     Mark   |  Grade   Mark   |  Grade    Mark   |  Grade
1     111   Alice      80         A        75        B       65         B       73      B
2     222   Frankline  75         B        60        B       50         C       62      B
```

I try to use this SELECT statement

```
<?php
$no = 0;
query = "SELECT * FROM student GROUP BY stu_id;"

$result_set =  mysqli_query($con, $query);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){

$no++;
?>
```

And apply some condition at the  as below

```
<td><?php echo $no; ?></td>                        
<td><?php echo $row['stu_name']; ?></td>

<!--This is for First-term -->
<?php if(($row['stu_exam'] == "First"){ ?>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_mark']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_grade']; ?></center></td>
<?php }
else {?>
<td><center></center></td>
<td><center></center></td>
<?php } ?>

<!--This is for Mid-term -->
<?php if(($row['stu_exam'] == "Mid"){ ?>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_mark']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_grade']; ?></center></td>
<?php }
else {?>
<td><center></center></td>
<td><center></center></td>
<?php } ?>

<!--This is for Final -->
<?php if(($row['stu_exam'] == "Final"){ ?>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_mark']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $row['stu_grade']; ?></center></td>
<?php }
else {?>
<td><center></center></td>
<td><center></center></td>
<?php } ?>
```

But the query just read the first list of the row in the table of each stu_id only and output it as below

```
No    ID    Name       First-term Exam     Mid-term Exam       Final Exam         Estimated
                       Mark   |  Grade     Mark   |  Grade   Mark   |  Grade    Mark   |  Grade
1     111   Alice      80         A        
2     222   Frankline  75         B
```

why? and i want to calculate the estimate mark(average) where sum of all marks of each exam divide by total marks of all taken exams. how to generate this values and update the generated value into the student table at the stu_est_mark and stu_est_grade attributes.

Comment: Group by collapses all your rows. This might be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351330/php-mysqli-group-by

Comment: @Chhitij but didn't i should GROUP BY it? because i need to collapse 3 rows to become 1 right? i'm sorry if i misunderstood the basic.. i'm a novice in this programming world..

Comment: Group By just collapses the rows into one. I think what you are referring to is joining and grouping

Comment: in my example above.. how should i group and join them?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I had made an error. Sorry for that. Change the first variable name to $q1 instead of $q2. It will work

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can be done is to get all the data from the database and then classify the marks as per student id within your php code.
Something like:

```
$q1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT(stud_id) FROM student");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1))
{
   $q2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student where stud_id=".$row['stud_id']);
   while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2))
   {
       //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: it results in only read 1 student and all her exam results. it shows 3 rows of Alice with her exam results in the respective column.

Comment: are you sure you have used the braces of the loops correctly? Because it is unexpected

Comment: ok now it output all results but in 6 rows.. 3 Alice, 3 Frankline. How to make it just 2 rows? 1 row for Alice with 3 exam results at the respective column and 1 row for Frankline with 3 exam results at the respective column.

Comment: that depends on your html. If you end the row and start a new one, only then the row will change. Make sure you use </tr> at the right place

Comment: Yikes iterated queries do not perform well.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM student GROUP BY stu_id;"
```

I'm a but rusty with my SQL but Group By might be the cause

try it just as

```
query = "SELECT * FROM student
```

if that doesn't work you might want to aggregate the 3 entries per student into one line using a join command in the query

Comment: it results in a table with 6 rows. 3 Alice and 3 Frankline with respective exam marks

Comment: how to aggregate the 3 entries per student into one line using a join command in the query?

Comment: ok thats good, at least its reading all the data and doing what its meant to,  now we just have to get it on 1 line and not 3,  are you using MySQL or MSSQL ?

Comment: after some quick research using pivot might help you here,  i haven't used this before so I'm not sure if it is helpful but ill add the link so you can have a look through

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
if (row['stu_exam']=='Mid')

== does not work as expected with string. So, try using === for strings.
```

Also try using elseif. That's why elif is created.

Comment: @Yun Try elif instead of if everywhere then.

Comment: how to apply elif? I've never heard about elif.

Comment: Elif is short for else if. Replace your second and third if with elseif @Yun. Sorry i typed elif. Its elseif